# What are the main tables that updated when we creating new product in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to know SQL Table Structure for adding new product.I don't want to any sql queries only want to know effecting tables names.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing the valuable information @Marius

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156086)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- `catalog_product_entity` - this one is the main product table. It contains the id, sku, attribute set and a few other details
- `catalog_product_entity_int|varchar|text|datetime|decimal` - these tables contain attribute values. Each attribute has a type and based on that type the value is inserted in the right table.
- `catalog_product_website` - this table contains the association of products on websites (product id, website id). If you don't add the products to at least a website nothing will be inserted here.
- `catalog_category_product` - this table contains the association between products and categories (product id, category id). if you don't assign products to categories nothing will be inserted here
- `catalog_category_product_index` - this tables also holds the association between products and categories but it is populated after reindexing.
- `catalog_product_entity_gallery`, `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`, `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` - these hold references to images assigned to products
- `catalog_product_link` this holds the links between products: cross-sells, up-sells, related products, child products of configurable & grouped products
- `catalog_product_link_attribute`, `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal|int|varchar`, hold the positions and other attribute values that might be related to the links above for the related products up-sells and cross-sells
- `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` contains the tier prices for the products
- `catalog_product_option` holds the product custom options
- `catalog_product_option_price` holds the custom options prices
- `catalog_product_option_title` holds the custom options titles
- `catalog_product_option_type_value` holds the custom options type values
- `catalog_product_option_type_price` holds the custom options price types
- `catalog_product_relation` holds a kind of redundant parent-child relation for configurable products
- `catalog_product_index_*` hold values for product attributes after reindexing
- `catalog_product_bundle_*` hold relations and options for bundle products
- `donwloadable_*` - hold data related to downloadable products

That's all I got. I hope I didn't miss anything.